# Preg replace numbers if more than 5 digits

Tags: php

I have an image upload form. After user submitted the form, my script will process the image and clean the image filename (im appending a unique number series at the end of the filename to prevent possible duplicate filename.

Often Im receiving filenames (after processing) such as

```
"c-id-1333-l-id-1298491-aid-3951-id-13995346097186883-im-193-1.jpg"
```

How can I preg_replace the numbers if its more than 5 digits, if less than 5 digit or less it will be retain. The above example should give `"c-id-1333-l-id--aid-3951-id--im-193-1.jpg"` (Dont mind the multiple consecutive dash[-], my script can handle this.

Comment: I'd say your best bet would be to catch the numbers (length) at the uploading stage, checking against the variable being used between `id` and `im` using [`strlen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and a conditional statement to boot, then performing the rest from thereon.

Comment: Not all post have that "id" and "im". Filename can be anything.

Comment: Still, you can based yourself on that; or check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to do this.

```
$str = 'c-id-1333-l-id-1298491-aid-3951-id-13995346097186883-im-193-1.jpg';
$str = preg_replace('/\d{5,}/', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Explanation:

```
\d{5,} # digits (0-9) (at least 5 times)
```

Output:

```
string(41) "c-id-1333-l-id--aid-3951-id--im-193-1.jpg"
```

If you want to retain `5` digits or less than 5 then you can use `\d{6,}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user supplied name important?

If it is not, one technique i like to do to normalize file names in that case is to simply hash them with something like sha1 or even md5. Then add your timestamp, and ids or what not to that, this takes care of a lot of issues with special characters such as ".", "\" and "/" ( dot dot dash and directory traversal ) in the file names.

@hwnd's regular expression should do the trick, but I though I would throw this out there.

so with hashing you'd get cleaner ( but less meaningful ) names like this

```
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709.jpg
```

then you can add your unique numbers on

```
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709-1234568764564558.jpg
```

you could even salt the filename with the timestamp first and then hash them to get filenames all 40 characters long, and the chance of hash collisions is very minimal unless your dealing with 10's of thousands of files, in which case just up the hashing to sha256 etc.